# Upper bound of the determinant of the sum of two matrices in terms of the determinant of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$, can we give an upper bound of $\det(A+B)$ in terms of $\det A$ and $\det B$? It would be great if the upper bound is sharp but I am also okay if not.

Comment: For one thing, there are easy ways to devise arbitrarily large values of $\det (A+B)$ with $\det A=\det B=0$.